# is there a way to reverse whatever happened to my phone today?

Tags: samsung-galaxy-s-4

I went snow shoeing today. Before setting out I turned off my phone. It's a Samsung Galaxy S4 on Verizon. After snowshoeing I turned it back on and everything was gone. it looks like it did some kind of reset:

- All of my apps were gone.
- my launcher was gone.
- my pictured were gone.
- my accounts were gone
- Everything was in Vietnamese

The only things preserved were my contacts. This might be because I use Backup Assistant Plus.

Does anyone have any idea what happened and if I can reverse it?

Answer (score 1):

It does look like it did a factory reset, I'm unsure why, but that appears to be the case. Did it get wet? or very cold?

Unfortunately, there is no way to recover all your data (unless you took a full backup onto your PC). However, as you probably know, many apps sync with the cloud, so it isn't that much of an issue.

If this happens again I would recommend contacting Samsung (if your phone is still under warranty).